# How do I keep functions out of the global namespace when using multiple files?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, gruntjs

Last time I built a large-scale application with JS I used require.js - which is great, but can be quite an overhead, especially if you don't want to load files asychronously, so this time I'm going without it.

This time I'm writing in pure JS and concatenating and minifying everything with Grunt (I'm a Grunt n00b here).  Because I'm keeping all the functions in separate files, I can't wrap everything in a closure like I could if I was using a single file.  What's the best solution to keeping all functions out of the global namespace?

I'm not sure I need a full dependency management solution, but I'd consider one if it's lightweight and simple.

Comment: Webpack, Webpack 2 will do this with JavaScript modules for you.

Comment: you need something, put everything under one global, maybe `require`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of common and easy to use JavaScript tools for managing application-wide dependencies by either implementing the CommonJS (the specification used by require.js) or the [ES2015 module specification](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/), including (as Benjamin suggested) [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), and [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/).

Comment: Yep, I think it's Browserify for me.  Looks much simpler than requirejs and plays nicely with Grunt.  I presume as soon as I put all of my code into modules I can pretty much forget about namespace pollution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without any dependency management tool you can for example use the [Revealing Module Pattern](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/taking-control-of-your-javascript-objects-with-the-revealing-module-pattern#the-revealing-module-pattern) and namespaces, simplified example:

**Top/Application file**

```
window.SomeApplication = (function () {
    // Add functions you want to expose to this
    this.require= function (path) { // Creates namespace if not already existing, otherwise returns reference to lowest level object in path
        var current = window,
                i;

        path = path.split('.');
        for (i = 0; i < path.length; ++i) {
            if (!current[path[i]]) {
                current[path[i]] = {};
            }
            current = current[path[i]];
        }

        return current;
    };

    return this;
})();
```

**Some other file**

```
SomeApplication.require('SomeApplication.SomeSubNamespace').SomeModule = (function () {
    // Module code

    return this;
})();
```

Then use your grunt concat and specify the top file first. This way you will only expose one item on the window object and your module will be accessible through `window.SomeApplication.SomeSubNamespace.SomeModule`.

Comment: I really like this answer as it shows you don't need a tool to do this stuff for you.  That being said, I've just spent an hour reading up on Browserify...